# From North of Italy to Greece via ship

Tags: italy, ferries, greece, ships

I'd like to go to Greece from North of Italy (example: Genoa) or South of France **via ship**.

**Is this route available nowadays with a ship / ferry?** Do you have any feedback about it, if you already experienced it?

Of course we could drive Italy from North to South by car, and then take a ferry from Apulia/Puglia (example: Bari).

I'd like to avoid the 2 or 3 days driving for ~2000 km (+ driving from France where we live), I don't particularly enjoy driving for several days in a row.

[image]

Also being on a ferry can be something enjoyable, especially for kids.

Comment: Genoa to Patras via the Strait of Messina is 1400 km.  I doubt that a ferry on a such a route would be economically viable, but if it were, it would take about 31 hours given a typical ship cruising speed of 45 km/hour.  Possibly a bit too long to remain enjoyable for the kids?

Comment: There used to be motorail services from northern to southern Italy, but it looks like all such have been withdrawn. Wikipedia claims there is also a motorail service from Belgrade to Thessaloniki, but I doubt this one still exists (the link is a 404).

Answer (score 13):

*The* go-to resource for ferries is [ferrylines.com](https://www.ferrylines.com/).

When I search for ferries from Italy to Greece, it lists 26 results:

[image: Ferries Italy to Greece screenshot]

We can readily see some of them are departing from the north.  Specifically, there are six lines from Venezia to Greece:

[image: Venezia to Greece]

You can use their search engine for yourself to look for further alternatives and information.  If you feel adventurous, you can consider the ferry from Trieste to Dürres, Albania, and then drive into Greece from there!

Comment: @EttoreP OP wants to bring a car, which means that the only trains that come into question are special car trains (motorail). I've seen how much stuff some people bring in and on their cars on Mediterranean ferries, and bringing that much on a train is most certainly not an option ):

Answer (score 3):

You have few possibilities:

The most used option, the ferry: Ancona to Igoumenitsa or Patras, twice a day.  I do not know if Ancona is too distant for you, but you should definitely check such ferries: they are frequent.

You may find also some ferries from Venice to Igoumenitsa and Patras, three times a week.

I cannot find a route from Genoa or France (no indirect routes).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Are there solutions from Italy west coast instead of east coast (Ancona, Venice)?

Comment: I found none, also with indirect stop (e.g. Algiers, Malta, South Italy).